# Can't get the string value in Hash Map on List view adapter in Android

Tags: android, listview, hashmap, listview-adapter

I already getting the string value from JSON but it seems to have the problem in Hash map or something, im getting null value on my List adapter. Can anyone help me or tell me if i did something wrong in my code. Thanks in advance. 
Here is my code.

The Activity -

```
public class TestJSON extends Activity{

    public static ListView lv;
    public static ProgressDialog pDialog;
    public static LazyAdapter adapter;

    static final String KEY_ITEMS = "items";
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_json_view);

        new AsyncInitial().execute();
        // Showing progress dialog before sending http request
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        //lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, items));
    }

    private class AsyncInitial extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {

            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
            }

            @Override
            protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                try {
                    //if (vid_num <= 0) {
                    // Get a httpclient to talk to the internet
                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    // Perform a GET request to YouTube for a JSON list of all the videos by a specific user
                    //https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author="+username+"&v=2&alt=jsonc
                    HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/SP86E04995E07F6BA8?v=2&start-index=1&max-results=50&alt=jsonc");
                    // Get the response that YouTube sends back
                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                    // Convert this response into a readable string
                    String jsonString = StreamUtils.convertToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
                    // Create a JSON object that we can use from the String
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);

                    // For further information about the syntax of this request and JSON-C
                    // see the documentation on YouTube http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_jsonc.html

                    // Get are search result items
                    JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray(KEY_ITEMS);

                    // Get the total number of video
                    //String vid_num = json.getJSONObject("data").getString("totalItems");
                    //System.out.println("vid_num-------->"+  vid_num);

                    // Loop round our JSON list of videos creating Video objects to use within our app
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        // The title of the video
                        String title = jsonObject.getJSONObject("video").getString(KEY_TITLE);
                        System.out.println("Title-------->"+  title);

                        // A url to the thumbnail image of the video
                        // We will use this later to get an image using a Custom ImageView
                        //String TAG_thumbUrl = jsonObject.getJSONObject("video").getJSONObject("thumbnail").getString("sqDefault");
                        //System.out.println("thumbUrl-------->"+  thumbUrl);

                        String id = jsonObject.getJSONObject("video").getString(KEY_ID);
                        System.out.println("video_id-------->"+  id);

                        map.put(title, KEY_TITLE);
                        map.put(id, KEY_ID);

                        menuItems.add(map); 

                    }


                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                //Log.e("Feck", e);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                //Log.e("Feck", e);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                //Log.e("Feck", e);
                }

                return menuItems;
            }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                adapter = new LazyAdapter(TestJSON.this,menuItems);    
                lv.setAdapter(adapter); 
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }


    }

}
```

And The adapter

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;

    public LazyAdapter(TestJSON testJSON, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems) {
        activity = testJSON;
        data = menuItems;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override   
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); 
        TextView id = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.artist);


        HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
        item = data.get(position);

        title.setText(item.get(TestJSON.KEY_TITLE));
        id.setText(item.get(TestJSON.KEY_ID));

        return vi;
    }

}
```

Comment: Change this  `adapter = new LazyAdapter(TestJSON.this,menuItems)` to `adapter = new LazyAdapter(TestJSON.this,results)` and try

Comment: @Raghunandan already did that but same output.

Comment: probably the keys are not matching. check the keys

Comment: Oh yeah i got it thanks, i was a fool did not check i have a wrong key value. it should be map.put(KEY_TITLE, title); map.put(KEY_ID, id);. Thanks @Raghunandan for helping me, thank for your generosity :D